# Missing Right Parenthesis Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out why my query is giving me this error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 2 Column: 10

from this code(edited):

```
SELECT 
  51,000 AS "Starting Principal",
  (51,000 + (51,000 * 0.10)) AS "New Principal",
  (.065*(51,000 + (51,000 * 0.10))) AS "Interest",
  (51,000 + (51,000 * 0.10)) + (.065*(51,000 + (51,000 * 0.10))) AS "Principal + Interest",
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS "System Date"
FROM Dual
```

If this helps, my query originates from my homework problem:

> 10. Use the Dual table to create a row with these columns:
>       Starting Principal Starting principle which should be equal to $51,000
>
> New Principal -> Starting principal plus a 10% increase
>   Interest -> 6.5% of the new principal
>   Principal + Interest -> The new principal plus the interest (add the expression you used for the new principal calculation to the expression you used for the interest calculation)
>
> Now, add a column named “System Date” that uses the TO_CHAR function to show the >results of the SYSDATE function when it’s displayed with this format:
>   'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
>   This format will display the day, month, year, hours, minutes, and seconds of the >system date, and this will show that the system date also includes a time.

Please help.

Comment: @pdrp I deleted my answer...too many typos to answer

Comment: How should your result data should look like. Kindly mention it, will be helpful to provide you solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use '.' in numbers ',' is a word separator.  Next, remove ';' in the middle of the statement. And finally more, don't omit '*' . That is

```
SELECT 51.000 AS "Starting Principal",
      (510.00 + (51.000 * 0.10)) AS "New Principal",
      (.065 *(51.000 + (51.000 * 0.10))) AS "Interest",
      (51.000 + (51.000 * 0.10)) + (.065 *(51.000 + (51.000 * 0.10))) AS "Principal + Interest",
      TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS "System Date"
FROM Dual;
```

Result

```
Starting Principal New Principal   Interest Principal + Interest System Date                            
------------------ ------------- ---------- -------------------- -----------------------------                              


                51         515.1     3.6465              59.7465                 11-sep-2016 15:27:42
```

Comment: So I have  implemented the fixes; however it is still giving me the error.

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 10

Comment: same error. I have posted the question in case of reference.

Comment: Added the result of the query.

Comment: I think the commas were group separators, so it would be 51000 not 51.000? Slightly unclear though... @Connexion in your latest edit you've left the commas in, so you've ignored an important (maybe most) part of the answer. [Read more about numeric literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00220).

Comment: @Serg, Thank you so much for your help. I have found my mistake, and it is fixed (error with the commas). I am very new to SQL programming, but it seems like many people just bash you on here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove last semicolon before from clause as below:

```
SELECT 51000 AS "Starting Principal"
  (51000 + (51000 * 0.10)) AS "New Principal"
  (.065 * (51000 + (51000 * 0.10))) AS "Interest"
  (51000 + (51000 * 0.10)) + (.065 * (51000 + (51000 * 0.10))) AS "Principal + Interest"
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS "System Date"
FROM Dual
```